# Combining multipole cells of text while preserving or setting formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I am trying to re write an excel formula in VBA because i need multiple steps to happen in the formula that excel cannot seem to complete correctly.

The excel formula I have is

```
=Z1&" "&TEXT(AA1,"MM/DD/YY")&": "&AB1&" "&AC1
```

Now I also need AC1 in this example to follow the format of number 0,000,000.0000. However, if the return of AC1 is a smaller number such as 10.5697, then the excel method would still show the number as 0,000,010.5697.

I would like to do this while only using the formatting needed. My thought was if I could format the individual cells in VBA then combine it might work best?? Any thoughts would be super helpful!

Comment: `TEXT(AC1,"0,000,000.0000")`

Comment: So I could do that in the excel formula, but then it provides the extra leading 0's that i am trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh, I missread, I thought you wanted the leading 0s.  If you do not want them then: `TEXT(AC1,"#,##0.0000")`